# vue create component from server rendered html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue instance already loaded with webpack which loads .vue files properly. However there are some files that I cannot use load as some of the html is rendered dynamically from the server.

Suppose I have a HTML file with the content below:

```html
<div id="test">
  <input type="text" :value="message"></input>
</div>
```

How do I create a vue component with the template above?

This was my attempt.

```js
const component = new Vue({
    name: 'test-component',
    el: '#test',
    data: {
        message: "hello world!"
    },
});
```

What I want rendered is

```html
<div id="test">
  <input type="text" value="hello world!"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: I think script run before HTML render therefore vue is not getting the element #test.

Comment: I tried to load 10 seconds after and still this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If neither render function nor template option is present, the in-DOM HTML of the mounting DOM element will be extracted as the template. In this case, Runtime + Compiler build of Vue should be used.

---- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#el

Comment: I already loaded the vue full with `'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'` in webpack.